# jQuery UI Datepicker in Rails 3 - Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, internationalization, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm Running Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2.

I have running the jQuery UI Datepicker, and I am trying to change the date format to dd-mm-yy.

According to the documentation, I have this for my Internationalization file:

```
jQuery(function($){
$.datepicker.regional['en-GB'] = {
    closeText: 'Done',
    prevText: 'Prev',
    nextText: 'Next',
    currentText: 'Today',
    dayNamesMin: ['Su','Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa'],
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    altFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: ''};
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['en-GB']);});
```

Which works...sort of.

When I select a date, it adjusts the format accordingly. The problem is, whenever I submit the form, it defaults back to the yy-mm-dd format.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Could you post the code of the forms element (and form submission, if it's not a straightforward button click)?

Answer (score 2):

A simple:

```
$('#myDateField').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'D, dd M yy' });
```

This works fine for me.

In some cases I had to do the following:

```
if params[:somedate] != ""
    some_date = Date.parse(params[:somedate])
    params[:mystuff]["some_date(1i)"] = some_date.year.to_s
    params[:mystuff]["some_date(2i)"] = some_date.month.to_s
    params[:mystuff]["some_date(3i)"] = some_date.mday.to_s
end
@mystuff.save
```